# Specific cast is not valid, while retrieving scope_identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I am getting exception: "Specific cast is not valid", here is the code

```
con.Open();
string insertQuery = @"Insert into Tender (Name, Name1, Name2) values ('Val1','Val2','Val3');Select Scope_Identity();";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tenderId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: have you tried splitting this into two SqlCommand objects? one for each query?

Comment: You do realize that you're executing the sql twice and therefore you are inserting the record twice. Just run the ExecuteScalar method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the interests of completeness, there are three issues with your code sample.

1) You are executing your query twice by calling `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteScalar`. As a result, you will be inserting two records into your table each time this function runs. Your SQL, while being two distinct statements, will run together and therefore you only need the call to `ExecuteScalar`.

2) `Scope_Identity()` [returns a decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(v=SQL.105).aspx). You can either use `Convert.ToInt32` on the result of your query, or you can cast the return value to decimal and then to int.

3) Be sure to wrap your connection and command objects in `using` statements so they are properly disposed.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        int tenderId = (int)(decimal)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
con.Open();
string insertQuery = @"Insert into Tender (Name, Name1, Name2) values ('Val1','Val2','Val3');Select Scope_Identity();";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
tenderId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

**EDIT**

It should be this as it is correctly pointed out that scope_identity() returns a numeric(38,0) :-

```
tenderId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

**Note:** You still need to remove the:-

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `Scope_Identity()` returns a decimal. The direct cast will not work, but a double cast will `(int)(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` or simply use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @anthony, yes you are correct, Its been a long time since I used this type of code

Answer (score 2):

Test the following first:

```
object id = cmd.ExcuteScalar()
```

Set a break point and have a look at the type of `id`. It is probably a `Decimal` and cannot directly be casted to `int`.

Comment: It's not the ID column that is the issue, it is the return value of `Scope_Identity()`. But you're right about the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

it needs Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());